# java.lang.IllegalAccessException - can not access a member of class org.springframework.data.jpa.util.HibernateProxyDetector with modifiers ""

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Basic Spring Data JPA application (NOT A Spring BOOT application). Does anyone have a clue what could be causing this issue:
Error:

```
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.
InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement
.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:344)
at org.springframework.beans.factory
.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.
invokeInitMethods
(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.
annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.
postProcessBeforeInitialization
(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:130)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Cannot instantiate factory class: 
org.springframework.data.util.ProxyUtils$ProxyDetector
    at org.springframework.core.io.
support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory
(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:117)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.
SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactories
(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:80)
    at org.springframework.data.util.ProxyUtils.
<clinit>(ProxyUtils.java:40)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class 
org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader 
can not access a member of class 
org.springframework.data.jpa.util.HibernateProxyDetector with modifiers ""
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:436)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.
SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:114)
```

Here are the relevent details:

pom.xml (Only using boot-starter dependencies for there ease of use. Because of integration issue with Apache James, its not a spring boot application)

```
<parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
      <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Configuration:

```
 @Bean
 LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
     LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lfb = new 
 LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
     lfb.setDataSource(dataSource());
 lfb.setPersistenceProviderClass
 (org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
     lfb.setPackagesToScan("com.######.######.model");
     lfb.setJpaProperties(hibernateProps());
     return lfb;
 }

 Properties hibernateProps() {
     Properties properties = new Properties();
     properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect",
 "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");
     properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql","true");
     return properties;
 }
 @Bean
 JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
     JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
     transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
 entityManagerFactory().getObject());
     return transactionManager;
 } 
 @Bean
 public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://mysql-james:3306/mailv2? 
 autoReconnect=true");
    dataSource.setUsername("######");
    dataSource.setPassword("########");
    return dataSource;
 }
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface BlockedEmailRepository extends 
CrudRepository<BlockedEmail, Long> {

List<BlockedEmail> findByUsernameAndEmailId(String username, String 
emailId);

}
```

Entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="BLOCKED_EMAIL")
public class BlockedEmail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "EMAIL_ID")
    private String emailId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
    private String username;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this issue because of the following conflict:

1. Apache James is using OpenJPA 2.4.2 as its persistence provider.
2. But in My code I was using Hibernate as the persistence provider.
3. We were trying to use Spring-Data-JPA, whereas James is not using Spring Data.

Hence, there were conflicts. To fix the issue, we extended the same OpenJPA configuration/implementation to apply to the data we were persisting and used same Persistence unit which was used by James and that solved our problem.